# Moving my sharepoint site title from left to right

Tags: css, layout, sharepoint-2013

I have modified my master page to move the site collection title from the body, to be inside my upper suite bar. So I move the following `h1` div code to be inside the Suite bar DIV as follow:-

```
<div id="suiteLinksBox">
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ControlId="SuiteLinksDelegate" runat="server" />
</div>

    <h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle" style="color:white;float:left">
      <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                  runat="server"
                  RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                      SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                  CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">
            <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
              <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
            </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
          </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
      <SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" CssClass="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap" runat="server">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none;">
          <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">&#160;</span>
        </a>
        <span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
        </span>
        <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
          _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");
        </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
      </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </h1>
```

The result is that the Site title (in my case the Dicusion forum) will be on the right side of the screen although i have defined `float:left` for the `h1` div, so is there a way to move it to the left just beside the logo ?

[image]

Can anyone advice please, if he know how to do it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 30px} will work fine